# How to use slot in Polymer 3?

Tags: html, polymer

I'm in the middle of updating my app from Polymer 1.9 to Polymer 3. I'm using legacy API for now to minimize the effort of rewriting old components, and I've enabled Shady DOM.

I allready know that Polymer doesn't support content tag, I'm trying to replace it with slot.
But unfortunatelly it doesn't work as expected.

My template is:

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
        <div class="component">
            <div class="header">My header</div>
            <div class="content">
                 <slot name="content"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-component'});
    </script>
```

HTML usage:

```
<my-component><div slot="content">Test content</div></my-component>
```

and the outcome is:

```
<my-component>
    <div class="component style-scope my-component">
        <div class="header style-scope my-component">My header</div>
        <div class="content style-scope my-component"></div>
    </div>
    <div slot="content">Test content</div>
</my-component>
```

Comment: It looks OK to me (ie should work), perhaps it is a bug in "legasy mode"? Could you convert this particular component to "pure Polymer 3" to see will it work then?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue; The `div` slot always replaced the placeholder slot inside the component in ShadyDOM (see [demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/candy-suit)). I tried both legacy mode and non-legacy mode.